# Recover curves from noisy collection of points

Tags: image-processing, noise, computer-vision, opencv, maximum-a-posteriori-estimation

Background: I'm trying to make a system that tracks a number of bubbles in a video

I'm implementing the bubble detection in the single image case using the Circular Hough Transform. Due to occlusion, blur and other factors, this detection will never be 100% accurate. I am tuning the detection procedure for high recall, possibly at the expense of precision.

Once this is done and applied to a sequence of frames from a video, I will have a number of detections that can be characterised as points in 4D space - x-position, y-position, radius and frame index.

Is there a procedure that can recover curves from this 4D point cloud?

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/recover-curves-from-noisy-collection-of-points)

Comment: apply a 4d median filter and then  manifold learning techniques (such as diffusion map etc..)

Comment: Have you considered prediction the motion of the bubbles ? That would allow smoothing over time, which could improve your results.

Comment: Some images might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very similar to the cell-tracking problem. This has been solved quite well using tracklet based approaches, where each object (bubble, cell etc) is modeled as a Maximum-a-Posteriori (MAP) estimation. The solution to which is through linear programming. 
You can get a good idea of the approaches and a [web-based implementation here](http://www.celltracking.ri.cmu.edu/algorithms.html)